# Filter by grouping two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, group-by, distinct

```
ID  Type    Status  
------------------------
1   Type1   Success 
1   Type1   Fail    
1   Type2   Fail    
2   Type3   Fail    
3   Type1   Success
```

I have above data

I want to filter this data group by Id and Type

For example, if there are multiple records for Id 1 and type1, I want to show only one record of this combination (irrespective of the status).

```
ID  Type    Status  
------------------------
1   Type1   Success 
1   Type2   Fail    
2   Type3   Fail    
3   Type1   Success
```

I tried using distinct and group by, but not getting proper result. (there are some other columns as well in this table)
This musu be very simple but I am not able to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT ID, Type, Status, ... rest of the fields here
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Type, Status, ... rest of the fields here, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type 
                            ORDER BY Status) AS rn
  FROM mytable) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

This will pick the record having the minimum `Status` value within the `ID, Type` partition.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN Then `ROW_NUMBER` is just what you need!

Comment: row_number() working fine for me. Thanks for the help

Comment: Accepting this as correct ans for using `ORDER BY Status`, we can use any other field here if we want most recent data of the group

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation.  If you don't care about `status`, just use `min()`:

```
select id, type, min(status) as status
from t
group by id, type;
```

If "don't care" really means "random", then use `row_number()` instead:

```
select id, type, status
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, type order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @MicrosoftDN . . . If you want them, then use the second solution.

Comment: row_number() working fine for me. Thanks for the help